# Display FormCollection with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view, actionresult, formcollection

I have a form using Html.BeginForm() on a view. I have in the controller an ActionResult to handle the post. What I need is to just kick back the results to a view. I can kick off the new view, but I don't know how to pass the data to it and once there I don't know how to display it. Here's what I have in the ActionResult.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
        {


            ViewBag.Title = "Confirm your order";
            return View("OrderConfirmation", collection);
        }
```

If I just do a return View("OrderConfirmation"); it will go to the view so I know I got that working. I just don't know how to pass the data. Right now I have it strongly typed to the same model the form was which causes errors because this FormCollection is not the same obviously. If I remove the strongly typed line the above works, but I have no idea how to loop through the collection at that point.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Use a ViewModel and a stongly typed view. Then you can pass the model to the second view.

```
public ActionResult Index(Order order)
{
  return View("OrderConfirmation", order);
}
```

ASP.NET MVC will automatically create an order instance and fill the properties from the posted FormCollection.

Comment: Took your advice and the answer below. Still having problems though. Check my reply below please.

Comment: You are talking about a foreach loop. I don't know the data structure you want to pass to the view. If you want to iterate over the data, you have to have a collection in your model. Maybe you should clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

First don't use FormsCollection, its too generic. You only need it if you need to unit test and access UpdateModel().

Bind to a model type or bind to params:

```
public ActionResult Index(SomeModel model)
{
  return View("OrderConfirmation", model);
}
```

or

```
public ActionResult Index(int key)
{
   SomeModel model = new SomeModel();
   UpdateModel(model);
  return View("OrderConfirmation", model);
}
```

in your view at the top specify

```
@model MyAppNameSpace.ViewModels.SomeModel
```

Comment: I've done as you said in the first instance. I removed the IEnumerable part on the view to make it look like your example. It didn;t work with that in there. It now works, but when it hits the foreach loop it dies saying "...does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Comment: change your foreach to run on  Model.WhateverPropertyIsYourCollection (guessing here without seeing your code)